# Gradle implementation vs compile in jar task

Tags: jar, build.gradle, executable-jar

I can successfully use *Gradle* to compile a fat JAR, but having trouble running the JAR after recently switching from the "compile" dependency specification to the "implementation/api" specification. I have isolated that the problem occurs in only one of the two following cases. The application runs in either case inside IntelliJ.

first/problem:

```
dependencies {implementation 'no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.18'}
```

second/works:

```
dependencies {compile'no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.18'}
```

The JAR compiles in both cases.  The problem appears when I attempt to start the first case JAR on the command line and it throws the following error.

> C:\aaa_eric\code\testr\mic\build\libs>java -jar mic-1.0-snapshot.jar
>   Error: Could not find or load main class app.MyApp
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tornadofx/App

Here is the JAR task in build.gradle. Is it possible that the tornadofx dependency is available at compile time, but not at run time? Thanks for any help.

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'app.MyApp'
  }
  from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing `configurations.compile.collect` to `configurations.compileClasspath.collect` fixed the problem for me.

I was having the same problem and stumbled across this in https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ConfigurationContainer.html:

> An example showing how to refer to a given configuration by name in
>   order to get hold of all dependencies (e.g. jars, but only)
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'java' //so that I can use 'implementation', 'compileClasspath' configuration
>
> dependencies {
>     implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26'
> }
>
> //copying all dependencies attached to 'compileClasspath' into a specific folder
> task copyAllDependencies(type: Copy) {
>     //referring to the 'compileClasspath' configuration
>     from configurations.compileClasspath
>     into 'allLibs'
> }
> ```

One thing to note is that `configurations.compileClasspath.collect` worked for me even when I was using the `compile` specification instead of `implement`.